# Inner products and distributive property

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, vectors

Is this true for the inner products ? :
$(\vec a + \vec b)\cdot(\vec c + \vec d) = \vec a\cdot\vec c + \vec a\cdot\vec d + \vec b\cdot\vec c + \vec b\cdot\vec d$.

Comment: It distributes like: $(\vec{a}+\vec{b})\cdot\vec{c}=\vec{a}\cdot\vec{c}+\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}$.

Comment: This should be true for any inner product - not just the standard one defined for vectors but also for example those defined for continuous functions. It should follow from the properties of the inner product.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed true.  It should be easy to confirm this by writing out the vectors explicitly in component form and evaluating both sides of the equality.

Remember that if $\mathbf{x} = \langle x_1, x_2, ..., x_n \rangle$ and $\mathbf{y} = \langle y_1, y_2, ..., y_n \rangle$, then:

$$\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} = \sum_{k=1}^n x_ky_k$$

Comment: Ok thank you ! Do you know if all the "classic" distributive properties applicable to scalar products ?

Comment: Indeed.  The associative, distributive, and commutative law all hold.  Even the product rule holds when taking derivatives!